# How to plot average value per month?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following function:

```
def plot_distribution(df, var, target, **kwargs):
    row = kwargs.get('row', None)
    col = kwargs.get('col', None)
    facet = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue=target, aspect=4, row = row, col = col)
    facet.map(sns.kdeplot, var, shade=True)
    facet.set(xlim=(0, df[var].max()))
    facet.add_legend()

plot_distribution(asma_df, var = 'ADDITIONAL_ASMA_40', target = 'RUNWAY', row = 'RUNWAY')
```

This function creates the following chart:

[image]

I want to change it in such a way that X axis contains average values of months, while the Y. axis contains average values of `ADDITIONAL_ASMA_40` per each month.

This is a sample DataFrame `df`:

```
month    ADDITIONAL_ASMA_40    RUNWAY
1        20                    32L
1        22                    32L
1        18                    32R
2        25                    32L
2        26                    32L
2        25                    32L
2        25                    32R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use groupby function

```
df.groupby('month').mean()
```

and plot its columns of interest

Comment: yeah, but I need to maintain splitting by RUNWAY as I showed. So, I do not understand how to adapt this approach to my function.

Comment: So, you would substitute each 'ASMA' by the avg ASMA of that month, right?